# I am exposing an object using <script type="text/json" id="myJSON"> on the webpage. Whats the best way to access it on the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

In my project we are write our code in AMD modules. My idea is to create an amd module, where I'll access the script tag using jquery id selector and then parse it to JSON.
For example:

```
<script type="text/json" id="myJSON">
{key1:"val1", key2:"val2", key3:"val3", key4:"val4"}
</script>


define(function() {
   var data = $('#myJSON').text();
   var json = JSON.parse(data);

   return json;
});
```

is this a good approach, or it there any better approach where we can write something like get(key) function to access the value of any key.

NOTE: Exposed object might be a nested object in future.

Answer (score 0):

The following will accomplish your goal. Note the formatting as it appears that your formatting is a touch off. :-) Hope this helps! Below I included an example of parsing and using the data to output values to the screen.

```js
let get = function( key ){
  let obj = $('#'+key);
  let rtn = false;
  if( obj ) rtn = JSON.parse( $( obj ).text() );
  return rtn;
}

let content = get("content");

$.each(content,function(k,v){

  let txt = $("<span>"+v+"</span><br/>");
  $('#output').append( txt );
  
});
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/json" id="content">
{ 
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2",
  "key3" : "value3",
  "key4" : "value4"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Angular (or something similar), put the data in the Angular controller, and simply display the scoped object in the HTML?

http://plnkr.co/edit/FYzKS7?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="MainController" ng-app="app">
  {{myObject}}
</div>
```

and

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.myObject = {
        cool_item : "my parents",
        cooler_item: "my parents got divorced",
        coolest_item: "my parents got divorced because of me"
      }
    }
  ]);
```